# Prototype Hide All elements of a class

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I can show/hide with IDs, however how do I do it with classes?

```
$('black').setStyle({
  display:'none', border:'1px solid red'
});
```

For example that will work if I had #black, but what if I have .black?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

```
$$('.black').each(
   function (e) {
      e.setStyle({border:'1px solid red'}); 
   } 
);
```

Comment: FYI, jQuery supports handling multiple elements without having to iterate explicitly:

    $('.black').hide();

... will hide everything with a class .black.

I hate to be 'that guy', but if you have the option, I highly recommend switching to jQuery.  jQuery has long since won the battle of the javascript libraries, owning roughly 90% of market share.  The only time I use Prototype is in supporting legacy applications.

Comment: agreed with siliconrockstar, I am in the same situation with you -- working on a legacy webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$$('.black').setStyle({
  display:'none', border:'1px solid red'
});
```

**More Info:**

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

Comment: Unfortunately I get.  TypeError: $$(".black").setStyle is not a function { message="$$(".large-black").setStyle is not a function",  more...} When $$(".black") returns 2 elements

Comment: @pondpad: Make sure you are using latest version of prototype.

Comment: Using 1.5.1.1, upgrading is not a option as various other parts rely on it.

Comment: `$$(".black").setStyle`does not work with prototype. You are probably thinking of JQuery.